# li element display inline in columns (grid)

Tags: html, css, grid, html-lists

I have `<li>` elements inside of an `<ol>` and would like to display it as shown below; can someone give me the css code to achieve this? I have generated these `<li>` elements with php so the HTML looks like this:

```
<ol>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>9</li>
   <li>10</li>
   <li>11</li>
   <li>12</li>
</ol>
```

and I would like to be displayed like this:

[image]

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Accessible-Touch-Friendly-Drag-Drop-Html-List-with-jQuery/

Above is an example, with jQuery, with that I am working channels editor and would like to get this like in image. I tried with display inline, width and height but no go, so I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not the best for older versions of IE, the only way I am aware of to achieve your desired results is by using the CSS3 `column-count` element.

**CSS**

```
li{
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: First: please put the standards-compliant CSS (the non-prefixed version) *after* the vendor-prefixed versions (to be sure that as the properties become standard the vendor-prefixed versions will be overridden, rather than continually used). Second, it's probably best *not* to refer to W3Schools, they have a (very) poor reputation here (despite *some* improvements in recent history).

Comment: Well noted, and fixed. Thanks!

Comment: You're quite welcome, note that I wasn't intending to say "don't post references, or links to documentation," (just advising that W3Schools links have garnered down-votes and criticism historically, and perhaps currently but I'm not sure). I'd *tend* to link to MDN's documentation (for readability) ([`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)), or to the W3C's documentation (for technical accuracy) [`column-count`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol/#cc).

Comment: Thanks...that's the simple solution yet...i never know that this css style exists...so this works perfect!